# System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Working database and Achive Database. I need to move unwanted entries (Isdeleted equal 1) into a archive database. I am having this error message.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'

Any suggestion on how and what approach i can do.

In My Model class

```
public partial class log
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int logID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> isDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual logCategory logCategory { get; set; }
}
```

In my actual database

```
Archive database Consist of: id, logID, isDeleted, logCategory
Working database Consist of: logId, isDeleted, logCategory
```

In my Controller

```
public class ProgrammingController : Controller
{
    dbArchive2Entities _Archivecontext = new dbArchive2Entities();
    dementiaDatabaseEntities _context = new dementiaDatabaseEntities();

    public ActionResult index()
    {
        testing();
        return View();
    }

    public void testing()
    {
        List<log> alldelLog = _context.logs.Where(x => x.isDeleted == 1).ToList();
        _Archivecontext.logs.Add(alldelLog[0]);
        _Archivecontext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line...

```
List<log> alldelLog = _context.logs.Where(x => x.isDeleted == 1).ToList();
```

...attaches `log`s to `_context`'s change tracker as [Entity Framework proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592886(v=vs.113).aspx). These proxies have a reference to the context by which they were created.

You can fix this by preventing `_context` from tracking the logs:

```
List<log> alldelLog = _context.logs
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.isDeleted == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: BTW, I don't understand why you only archive the first deleted log.

Comment: Hi Arnold, I will test it out later. if first index don’t work, all will not work as well. Just trying them out. Thanks

Comment: @arnold After adding the notracking, this error occurs System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already a generated proxy type for the object layer type 'ArchiveASPNET.Models.log'. This occurs when the same object layer type is mapped by two or more different models in an AppDomain.'

Comment: I have found my solution it is because of lazy loading. Lazy loading doesn't work well with serializing. The problem can be seen here. Thank you arnold

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes indeed, I didn't get this exception in a simple scenario. To be really safe add `_context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` as the first thing when `_context` is created. That also disables lazy loading.